# Force Delphi to open a project with chdir the project's dir

Tags: delphi, directory, chdir

I have Delphi 6 prof, with Win7.
We have many projects. Some of them are favourites, commonly used/edited.

Formerly I used GExperts' fav. files that is shown in "Open dialog" for this.
But this is vanished with Win7.

The main problem that Delphi don't forcable to use a folder as initial folder.
What's this meaning?

When I start a Delphi with clicking on a dpr, or start with a link that points to Delphi + the needed dpr, Delphi remains in the prev. dir.
Ok, the project is opening, but I'm in the last dir that used in Delphi.
No matter that I shut down, and open the Delphi again. It is remaining in this folder.

Delphi can opens the project dir in two times:
- a.) select a dpr with opendialog
- b.) use the "closed projects" (but this have only 4 items, no more)

I tried many things.
I tried to use batchfile that prev. opens the needed dir, and next start the Delphi with the needed project.
I tried to set "starting folder" in a link. I try to find the dirs...

But no matter what I did, Delphi not use the project's folder.

This problem, because we have many same folder, and I easily miss something, confuse files, because I think I'm in good directory.

Do you have some idea, how to force Delphi to open the folder where the actual project is in?

Thanks for your help:
   dd

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's a registry setting. Look at the registry and try editing the relevant values there (I don't have D6 handy, and I know it's changed in D2010 which is what I have right now).

Comment: Somebody spoken in other list that OpenDialogs are keep their last paths in Windows. If the application not set this, they get the last.
So it is may OpenDialog problem.
I tried to find the last directory in the registry but I don't found it...